# Dynamically enable a jquery ui button that was previously disabled on javascript event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-button

I have two divs.  Clicking on a jqueryui button (button1) in first div (div1) creates a jquery ui button (button2) in the second div (div2) with a data element identifying the button1 that created it; also the click hides (or disable works too) the clicked button (button1).

When i click on button2, i want to show/enable button1; however, this does not work. This seems to be a problem only with dynamically hidden/disabled buttons.

```
<div id="pane1>
    <a id="123" class="addme jqb">Add</a>
</div>
<div id="pane1>
    <a id="345" data-target='123' class="deleteme jqb">Delete</a>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('.jqb').button();
  $('.deleteme').button('disable');
  $('.addme').on("click", function(){
    $(this).button('disable');
    $('.deleteme').button('enable');
  });
  $('.deleteme').on("click", function(){
    $(this).button('disable');
    $('#123').button('enable');
  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle containing the simplified version of the code - https://jsfiddle.net/x7u1xLg8/16/

Comment: What is wrong inside the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your HTML is not correct. For instance, you forget to close the double quotes. That will fail silently and have weird consequences.

```
<div id="pane1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.   The actual code is different/more elaborate and i accidentally made the mistake here, but i guess a similar markup issue could be causing the problem

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem, I can definitely help. Otherwise I don't think anyone can, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `""` in two place:

> `<div id="pane1>`

```
    <a id="123" class="addme jqb">Add</a>
  </div>
```

> `<div id="pane1>`

```
    <a id="345" data-target='123' class="deleteme jqb">Delete</a>
 </div>
```

Please check the updated code(Note check the code in fiddle).

```js
$(function(){
 $('.jqb').button();
  $('.addme').on("click", function(){
   $(this).button('disable');
    $('#345').button('enable');
  });
  $('.deleteme').on("click", function(){
   $(this).button('disable');
    $('#123').button('enable');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="pane1">
    <a id="123" class="addme jqb">Test</a>
</div>
<div id="pane1">
    <a id="345" data-target='123' class="deleteme jqb">Test1</a>
</div>
```